# JavaScript : Replace all character by empty after a specific character

Tags: javascript, string

I have this String :

```
var test = "toto@test.com";
```

I would like to replace all character after the "@" character by empty value.
I would like to get this String :

```
var test = "toto"
```

Comment: If you got your answer, kindly mark it accepted, if not please mention the issue..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
test= test.split('@')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"toto@test.com".replace(/@.+$/, '')
```